# removing duplicate characters next to each other

Tags: php, string

im trying to remove duplicate characters that are directly next to each other

1,2,3,4,5 - has a few commas but they are not to be removed
1,,2,,3,,4,,5 - would have to be turned into the regular 1,2,3,4,5 no matter how many commas are inbetween each number i would like to have just one. i have something similar which makes sure there are no commas at the end of the string:

```
$n = "1,2,3,4,5";
for ($i=0;$i< strlen($n);$i++) {

    if (substr($n, -1) == ',') {
        $n = substr($n, 0, -1);
    }
}
```

would appreciate some help on this matter,

Thanks :)

Comment: What's your question? If there's a better way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Looks like you only want to do this with commas, so it's extremely easy to do with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$n = '1,2,,3,,,,,4,5';
$n = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $n);     // $n == '1,2,3,4,5'
```

Also you can replace the code you gave above that makes sure there are no commas at the end of a string with [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php). It will be faster and easier to read:

```
$n = '1,2,3,4,5,,,,,'
rtrim($n, ',');                         // $n == '1,2,3,4,5'
```

You can combine them both into a one-liner:

```
$n = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', rtrim($n, ','));
```

Comment: That did the trick. wasn't really sure how I could of used regular expressions in php. now i know :D thank you.

Comment: @Steve No problemo! There are a few different functions for using regular expressions in PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Comment: oh thanks for editing with additional information, rtrim almost did exactly what i already had at the end. it got every comma at the end except one. so i just used if (substr($n, -1) == ',') {
 $n= substr($n, 0, -1); to get that last one. thank you again :)
}

Comment: @Steve You're welcome. `rtrim($n, ',')` should strip every comma from then end though.

Answer (score 16):

```
$n = '1,2,,3,,,,,4,5';
$n = preg_replace('/(.)\\1+/', '$1', $n);
```

This *should* work for any duplicate characters immediately following one another.

However, it is unlikely that the asker wants to replace *any* character repetitions in this way (including numbers like 44 => 4). More likely, something like this is intended:

```
$n = preg_replace('/([,.;])\\1+/', '$1', $n); # replace repetitions of ,.:
$n = preg_replace('/([^\d])\\1+/', '$1', $n); # replace repetitions of non-digit characters
```

Comment: While this may not have been what he wanted, this is what he asked for in his question so +1.

Comment: this will remove repeated numbers too , and my cause problem. `'1,2,,3,,,,,44,55';` will be `1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: As the @MrWednesday commented, I have answered the question as asked, even if it is highly unlikely that the asker wanted what they asked :) However, your remark is quite realistic and I'll amend the answer.