# php preg_replace duplicate string on multiple lines

Tags: php, preg-replace, duplicates

I have the following file example:

apple,
cherry,
,(remove)
pear,
, (remove)
grapes,
watermelon

I've used the following expression

```
preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $n);
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10342441/1880254) answer.

This works fine but only if the file is on one line:

```
apple, cherry,, pear,,...
```

How do I extend the expression to remove excess duplicates on multiple lines so the file reads:

apple,
cherry,
pear,
grapes,
watermelon

Here is the code:

`foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

    if ($line[0] === '.') {
    $compare_line = $line;
    $compare_line = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $compare_line);
    echo $compare_line;
    }
}`

Comment: if you have only limited number of extra commas (and you are 100% sure), like only 2 or 3 duplicates you can use str_replace(array(',,,',',,'),',',$n) is faster.

Comment: It would never be more than ',,' two commas.  The issue is removing the extra comma that stands alone on a newline.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are doing something to split the lines and then only applying the regex to the first line. Try just doing this:

```
file_put_contents("newfile.txt",preg_replace("/,+/", ",", file_get_contents("oldfile.txt")));
```

Comment: Yes, I used foreach($lines as $line_num => $line).  I will give this a try.  Thanks

Comment: No, this did not do what I was looking to do because I am looking for specific strings and must find the appropriate ones before adding them to a new file.

Comment: +1 good answer! if the OP wants something more specific he should post his code, the input, expected results and actual results.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the example and added the foreach that shows the required task.

Answer (score 0):

You can make preg_replace handle all the lines as one single line by adding the flag `/s` to the end of the expression.

```
preg_replace('/,+/s', ',', $n);
```