# PHP if character repeated more than one time

Tags: php, detection, repeat

I have a function that adds random dots to a string and stores the altered string in a variable, however, sometimes it adds multiple dots in a row. For example:

```
te...stin.g
```

or

```
t..e.st.in.g
```

or

```
te.st.in....g
```

...and so on.

I was wondering, how can I detect if there are multiple dots in a row, and just make them into one. So for example the first string above would become:

```
te.stin.g
```

the second...

```
t.e.st.in.g
```

the third...

```
te.st.in.g
```

...and so on.

How can I accmplish this with PHP? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing duplicate characters next to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342423/removing-duplicate-characters-next-to-each-other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\.{2,}/', '.', $string);
```

`{2,}` means 2 or more of the preceding expression, which is a literal `.`.

Go to [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) to learn all about regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You may edit your function so that it no more adds multiple dots in a row. Anyway, if that isn’t the expected behaviour of your function, apply `preg_replace` to its output in order to get rid of those multiple dots. Let’s say `$str` is the output of your function. Then:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\\.{2,}/", ".", $str);
```