# PHP - remove duplicate pipe symbols

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove duplicate pipe symbols from a string with a comma between them. Let's say I got this string:

```
$mystring = '| | Apple | Pear | | | Banana | | Cherry';
```

Then the desired output should be:

```
| Apple | Pear | Banana | Cherry';
```

A similar question is asked here:

[removing duplicate characters next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342423/removing-duplicate-characters-next-to-each-other)

However, when I apply the proposed preg_replace function (as stated in the most popular answer in that topic) to my string, I got a PHP error: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 2.

This is what I tried:

```
$mystring = preg_replace('/ |+/', ' |', $mystring);
```

Does anyone know how to remove the double pipe-symbols and replace them with just 1 between the words? Thanks.

Comment: Are you generating it from some array?

Comment: No. I get the strings from an external source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like quite a simple `preg_replace` call:

```
echo trim(preg_replace('/[ |]+/', ' | ', $mystring));
```

## [demo](https://eval.in/481524)

`[ |]+`: Basically matches all spaces and pipe chars in between words here, and replaces them with the string *" | "*. Because we're adding a leading and trailing space, I'm passing the result to `trim` to remove those spaces from the start (and end) of the output.

Comment: Thank you sir, this works fine. I forgot to add the brackets [ ] because they weren't used in the other question. Might be because there was only 1 symbol involved there (a single comma).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is better solution, but this will certainly help you,

```
$mystring = '| | Apple | Pear | | | Banana | | Cherry';
echo implode(" | ",array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("|",$mystring)))));//echoes Apple | Pear | Banana | Cherry
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/481514)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a whitespace character:

```
/[|\s*]+/ - matches |  | or | |
/[|\ ]+/  - matches  | |
```

Code:

```
<?php
$mystring = '| | Apple | Pear | | | Banana | | Cherry';
$mystring = preg_replace('/[|\s*]+/', ' | ', $mystring);
echo $mystring;
```

Output:

```
| Apple | Pear | Banana | Cherry
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/481536)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
$mystring = '| | Apple | Pear | | | Banana | | Cherry';

echo preg_replace("/[\| ]+/", " | ", $mystring);
```

**Output**

```
| Apple | Pear | Banana | Cherry
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/481539)