# PHP: Turn same following multiple slash characters `///` into single slash `/` character

Tags: php, regex

I have a duplicate dynamic number of slash `/` characters in my variable, for example:

```
$string = 'test////test2';
$string2 = '///test//test3';
$string3 = 'xsss/////ss/';
```

i want to remove duplicate `/` slash character next to each other. so it only leaves one `/`slash character, like this:

```
$string = 'test/test2';
$string2 = '/test/test3';
$string3 = 'xsss/ss/';
```

I already tried the suggestion from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10342441/11920674)

```
$string = preg_replace('/,+/', '/', $string);
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
```

but it's not working at all, it's still outputting the original string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it with `preg_replace`

Just changed it to detect one or more `/` instead of `,` (`\/+` rule):

```
$re = '/\/+/';
$str = '///test//test3';

echo preg_replace($re, '/', $str); //outputs /test/test3
```